# Terraform not updating the new TDE KEY in SQL server

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I configured TDE key long back & now I want to use new TDE key so from terraform variable I am passing the new tde_key_name like below.

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "root_keyvault" {
  name                = var.keyvault_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_key" "tde_key" {
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.root_keyvault.id
  name         = var.tde_key_name
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_server_transparent_data_encryption" "tde-key-new" {
  server_id        = var.server_id
  key_vault_key_id = data.azurerm_key_vault_key.tde_key.id
}
```

But the SQL server not being updated in portal and I am seeing old TDE key. Anything I am missing here or some bug is associated with terraform provider ?

Comment: What is the plan output?

Comment: @Marcin  1> The azurerm_key_vault_key is read properly the keyvault key name
2>azurerm_mssql_server_transparent_data_encryption  the key is loading the old tde key

Comment: As @Marcin suggested please show us your plan file.  Also you could add a debug output with the value `data.azurerm_key_vault_key.tde_key.id` like so `output "tmp_dbg_output_tde_key_id" { value = data.azurerm_key_vault_key.tde_key.id }` to check the value of that expression.

Answer (score 0):

It takes time for the updated TDE to reflect if any changes are detected

**Code:**

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                        = "myexamplekvk"
  location                    = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days  = 7
  purge_protection_enabled    = false

  sku_name = "standard"

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

    key_permissions = [
      "Get", "List", "Create", "Delete", "Update", "Recover", "Purge",
    ]
    

    secret_permissions = [
      "Set",
      "Get",
      "Delete",
      "Purge",
      "Recover",
      "List"
    ]

    storage_permissions = [
      "Get","Set"
    ]
  }
  access_policy {
    tenant_id = azurerm_mssql_server.example.identity[0].tenant_id
    object_id = azurerm_mssql_server.example.identity[0].principal_id

    key_permissions = [
      "Get", "WrapKey", "UnwrapKey"
    ]

    secret_permissions = [
      "Set",
      "Get",
      "Delete",
      "Purge",
      "Recover",
      "List"
    ]

    storage_permissions = [
      "Get","Set"
    ]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "example" {
  name         = "byok"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  key_type     = "RSA"
  key_size     = 2048

  key_opts = [
    "unwrapKey",
    "wrapKey",
  ]

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault.example
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_server_transparent_data_encryption" "example" {
  //auto_rotation_enabled = false
  server_id        = azurerm_mssql_server.example.id
  key_vault_key_id = azurerm_key_vault_key.example.id
}




resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "tdekey" {
  name         = "mytdekey"
  value        = azurerm_key_vault_key.example.id
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}
```

[image]

[image]

***I stored the generated TDE key in key vault secret and then created new one .***

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "tdekey" {
  name         = "mytdekey"
  value        = azurerm_key_vault_key.example.id
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}
```

**Code:**

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "root_keyvault" {
  name                = azurerm_key_vault.example.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}
data "azurerm_key_vault_key" "tde_key" {
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.root_keyvault.id
  name         = azurerm_key_vault_key.example.name
}



resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "newexample" {
  name         = "byok1"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  key_type     = "RSA"
  key_size     = 2048

  key_opts = [
    "unwrapKey",
    "wrapKey",
  ]

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault.example
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_server_transparent_data_encryption" "tde-key-new" {
  server_id        = azurerm_mssql_server_transparent_data_encryption.example.server_id
  key_vault_key_id = azurerm_key_vault_key.newexample.id
}


    
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "newtdekey" {
  name         = "mynewtdekey"
  value        = azurerm_key_vault_key.newexample.id
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}
```

[image]

[image]

To check I stored them in secrets in keyvault and compared and both are different.
Could get the new key ,

> old key :
> https://examplekvk.vault.azure.net/keys/byok/d4e8646exxxx0ae2dd0bc
>
> new  key :
> https://examplekvk.vault.azure.net/keys/byok1/ccda2cf3xxxxx92c5572

see [Customer-managed transparent data encryption (TDE) - | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/transparent-data-encryption-byok-overview?view=azuresql)

***It will take upto 10 mins -30 mins to detect the change in the TDE key or its version.***

> ***Note: Always store the older TDE protector versions in Azure
> Keyvault for it to update to new one and for back up purpose.***

Even when auto_rotation_enabled is set to true , the server will be reflected with the rotated with new key in 60 mins

**Reference:** [azurerm_mssql_server_transparent_data_encryption | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/mssql_server_transparent_data_encryption)

Comment: I am creating KEYS in AKV directly and even using these keys for DB backup too. Changes are not detecting. I deleted the old key by taking backup and done provision but failed as while provisioning it tried to connect to AKV and failed as old key was not there. But will continue checking and update here.